# Logstash wont talk to Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have Elastic Search 1.3.2 via [ELMA](https://code.google.com/p/enterprise-log-management-appliance/). The ELMA setup places ES REST API behind an Apache reverse proxy with SSL and basic auth.

On a separate host, I am trying to setup Logstash 1.4.2 to forward some information over to ES. The output part of my LS is as follows:

```
output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
  elasticsearch {
    host => "192.168.248.4"
}
```

This produces the following error:

> log4j, [2014-09-25T01:40:02.082]  WARN: org.elasticsearch.discovery: [logstash-ubuntu-jboss-39160-4018] waited for 30s and no initial state was set by the discovery

I then tried setting the protocol to HTTP as follows:

```
elasticsearch {
  host => "192.168.248.4"
  protocol => "http"
```

}

This produces a connection refused error:

```
Faraday::ConnectionFailed: Connection refused - Connection refused
```

I have then tried setting the port to 9200 (which gives connection refused error) and 9300 which gives:

> Faraday::ConnectionFailed: End of file reached

Any ideas on how I can get logstash talking to my ES?

Comment: I think this question is better phrased as follows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26045235/getting-logstash-to-talk-to-elastic-search-with-https-basic-auth

Answer (score 0):

The way to inform logstash to set output in ES is :

`elasticsearch {
        protocol => "http"
        host => "EShostname:EsportNo"
  }`

In your case, it should be,

`elasticsearch {
        protocol => "http"
        host => "192.168.248.4:9200"
  }`

If it's not working, then the problem is with the network address configuration.In order to make sure you have provided the correct configuration,

- Check the `http.port` property of ES
- Check `network.bind_host` property of ES
- Check `network.publish_host` property of ES

Comment: Thanks @Nirdesh. My Elastic Search is running inside the ELMA appliance. Access to REST API is via SSL with basic authentication.

Comment: @Nirdesh To my understanding from the [host](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-host) and [port](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-port) sections of the logstash output plugin documentation, it is not necessary for hosts mentioned in the `host` parameter so that should not be an issue.