# Getting Logstash to talk to Elastic Search with HTTPS + Basic auth

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have Elastic Search as part of the [ELMA appliance](https://code.google.com/p/enterprise-log-management-appliance/). This appliance presents ES via HTTPS protected by basic auth. I have Logstash running on a separate machine. This Logstash needs to send log data to ES. What is the right output configuration to use?

Thanks for any pointers.

-Raj

Comment: Looks like basic auth is a recent addition: https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-902. Looking for HTTPS support.

Answer (score 1):

there is an option in new version:

http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-password

ssledit

Value type is boolean
Default value is false
SSL Configurations (HTTP only)

Enable SSL

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Logstash's elasticsearch_http module does not support SSL, or does not handle self-signed certs. My solution was to disable SSL on the ElasticSearch httpd conf entry in the ELMA appliance.